# Single Threaded Server Implementation to Multi Threaded

Tags: java, android, multithreading

Guys I want to convert my server implementation into multi thread so that it can handle multiple requests. Basically the server is connected with an android application and it is recieving an image from android application. I want to add a thread so that it can handle multiple requests and the thread should start when the request is recieved. Kindly help me out.

This is the Server Code.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws UnknownHostException, IOException, MatlabInvocationException, MatlabConnectionException {
    while (true) {
        try {
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(4001); // Server socket

        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Could not listen on port: 4001");
        }
        System.out.println("Server started. Listening to the port 4001");

            clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
            DataInputStream inputFromClient = new DataInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());
            int count = inputFromClient.readInt();
            int available = inputFromClient.available();
            System.out.println("Length of Image in Bytes:" + count);
            System.out.println("available:" + available);
            image = new byte[count];
            inputFromClient.readFully(image);
            System.out.println(image.length);
            System.out.println(image);
            final BufferedImage bufferedImage = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(image));
            ImageIO.write(bufferedImage, "jpg", new File("image.jpg"));
            System.out.println("Image has been wriiten in the directory.");

        MatlabProxyFactory mpf = new MatlabProxyFactory();
        MatlabProxy proxy = mpf.getProxy();
        proxy.eval("conclusion=DetectColorL");
        Object[] obj = proxy.returningEval("conclusion", 1);
        String Message = obj[0].toString();
        DataOutputStream outTo = new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
        outTo.writeUTF(Message.toString());
        System.out.println(Message);
        proxy.disconnect();
        serverSocket.close();
```

Comment: Link to a framework I put together for multi-client server socket: http://sourceforge.net/p/tus/code/HEAD/tree/tjacobs/io/ServerSocketEx.java

Comment: @ControlAltDel Where I will give the Port number in that code???

Comment: new ServerSocketEx(myServerPort)

Answer (score 1):

To make it multithreaded you want to be able to have multiple clients connected at the same time, to handle multiple requests instead of one at a time.

To do so, your server will have to permanently accept new clients.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ServerSocket serverSocket;

    try {
        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(4001); // Server socket
        System.out.println("Server started. Listening to the port 4001");

        while (true) {
            // Always accept new clients
            Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept(); 
            new RequestHandlingClass(clientSocket).start(); // Make a new thread and call it's run procedure
        } 

    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Could not listen on port: 4001");
    }      
}
```

Now our server accepts multiple clients we have to implement the `RequestHandlingClass` class. You want that class to listen for client requests and handle them.

```
public class RequestHandlingClass() extends Thread {
    Socket clientSocket;        
    DataInputStream inputFromClient;

    RequestHandlingClass(Socket clientSocket) {
        this.clientSocket = clientSocket;
        this.inputFromClient = new DataInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());
        // ...
    }

    public void run() {
        // Handle client requests
    }
}
```

Based on your question I suppose you want to execute the "image handling" code in the `run` method.

Comment: In run method I will give the Image Handling, Matlab Proxy Code and return message code to Android application???

Comment: In the thread you should handle everything that is specific to **that** client.

Comment: The main point for the hand-off is not Image Handling, etc. It is reading and processing data coming in from the socket

Comment: @ControlAltDel of course, but in his case this data has to do with image handling, that's why I wrote it as it is (i thougt it would be clearer for the OP).

Comment: @HyperZ lol we're both trying to out-"clearer" each other. Your point is a good one

Comment: @HyperZ lol It is not running .......... one mobile application runs fine while other application on the other mobile crashes